# Best form for NAND transformation

Tags: nand

What is the best form to transform a logic function to before to convert all gates to NANDs, so that we have a minimal number of NAND gates?
Is it minimal sum of products, minimal product of sums or something else?
The same question for NOR.

Comment: There is no formal method for *minimal* representation of a function using NAND/NOR. There are some heuristic-based algorithms to do that, but it is way too broad.

Comment: OK thank you. Can make your comment an answer so I can choose it?

Comment: I don't think this comment deserves to be an answer :)

Comment: a somewhat more general question that I remember answering: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195557/is-there-a-systematic-way-to-simplify-multiple-output-boolean-functions/195619#195619

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRO_Bgyp9P4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no perfect method. But if you wanna design a logic circuit , then you may calculate cost ( number of gates + number of each gates input ). Sometimes SOP contains the minimum cost , sometimes POS .

You can reduce number of gates by following some methods like Multilevel Synthesis, Functional Decomposition .

If you wanna design a logic IC , you should go for CMOS logic circuit design.